# Tips for surfing on the coast to the North Sea/English Channel

Tags: europe, france, belgium, camping, surfing

I was wondering if anyone could share some tips for good surf spots around Netherlands, Belgium and Northern France. I am planning on going sometime in the winter/spring and would like to wild camp. Only for around 3 days though.

Gear for winter camping is no problem. I was wondering what kind of surf gear you guys use and what good spots are. Also is there some etiquette for those spots and has anyone every tried surfing with a dry suit?

Thanks!

Comment: WaveSurfing or WindSurfing or both?

Comment: And yes surfing in a dry suit is no problem and a must when we go surfing around xmas in Sweden otherwise you will freeze to much

Comment: WaveSurfing! Are there special surfing drysuits or will any drysuite with enough range of movement do?

Comment: There are surfing specific dry suits but as you say all they have is better movement, so as long as you feel comfy and can move around enough  any dry suit will do, important to get good fitting shoes as well and make sure the fit is good so you dont get to much water in, because it will be cold but done correctly like I said I have been surfing 4 meter waves at xmas in sweden so it can be done and nothing beats the feeling

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I can't upvote comments yet. But you helped a lot.

Comment: Mibi, as question owner you can upvote answers, (which is where the information should be posted,) and you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wave surfing in the Netherlands, Wijk aan Zee/Velsen Noord beach, also known as Noord pier, (North pier).

As far as the locals know it is the only place in the country with useful waves often enough to consider to have gear handy.
It is not a good surf spot, it is the only one that offers any challenge.

Looking at [this webcam site,](https://www.surf-forecast.com/breaks/Wijkaan-Zee-Noordpier/webcams/latest) the locals may not know all the locations.
Those locations I recognize all have man made structures on or as part of the coast, although I do not guaranty that there are no natural surf beaches at all.

The Belgian and Dutch coast is sandy beach, without natural rocky bottoms, making for a lack of surfable waves.

No wild camping allowed in the Netherlands and as the few surf spots are in a crowded areas, it is rather likely you will not get away with it. Camp grounds are around but may all be closed outside the season.

I am not that familiar with the French coast and the results there will depend on what you include in your search area.

As mentioned in the comments on the question, dry suits for surfing do work. (They are also for rent in at the Noord pier surfing shops.)
As I do not surf but have worked with someone who did surf on Noord Pier, I know there is a community of regulars who surely have local traditions.
If you do have the time, search for a facebook group or some such, and see if you can find information online. (I can not do much for you there as I do not do facebook nor know what to ask about.)